# PHP OO: Best strategy for dealing with form posts?

Tags: php, oop

We have built custom forms and at this stage are built very well with a lot of thought. Each class has its own responsibility and so far the basic principle of OOP concepts have been used i.e. inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation, etc. Each element of the form is an object and all objects are collected and initiated on the fly.

Now weve got to the processing part of the forms we at a loss for a strategy to deal with this and would like to ask if anyone has any pointers please?

Is there an alternative, say for instance the creation of a class that could be responsible for checking if the form has been submit and methods to gather post data, validate, etc or do people still do the old way like a quick conditional in the client to check if form submit:

```
if(isset($_POST["var"])
{
//process form
} else {
//show form
}
```

And would it be best to use a separate action page to process?

Bascially what I dont want to do is have to write some awful code thats not reusable or make use of OOP concepts. We would like to achieve something WITHOUT USING ANY FRAMEWORKS.

Comment: How is OOP related to what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: yes123 is partially right, what i think you need to do is use the patterns that mvc uses. Time and again people think that Yii or Zend is MVC. It's not it is a framework that uses MVC patterns and adds a shed load of extra's as well. (OK different argument). However i think if you dived into patterns it would help. then you can just implement the code you need. If brave try the Gang of Four book or get one that deals with GOF patterns in PHP, or web sites that give examples. OOP is way of writing the code not a way of building web sites. p.s. also look at how the fw's tackle it, code read!

Comment: Thanks PurplePilot, a little more constructive than yes123 comments...

Comment: Totally missing the point 'sombe'. Whats been achieved already has much to do with OOP, the question was how to follow that path with what we are now trying to achieve. Why comment if nothing good to say?

Comment: @Steve - the question seems too general-purpose and very broad to cover. If for some reason, frameworks are not your thing, then you could certainly use them for inspiration. Generating and processing forms is at the heart of most of these frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I think most people commenting are reading too much into the question to be honest. Was just curious as to peoples thoughts or would be approach on form processing in OOP without frameworks. We are not looking for the best solution or to reinvent the wheel but implement this as part of the work we have already done mainly just to develop our own practices in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to go with structure like this :

```
// public function __construct( ValidatorInterface $validator )
$form = new Form( new Validator );


// public function add_field( $name , array $rules = array() )
$form->add_field( 
   'name',  
    // that would be $_POST['name'] , and in template file <?php echo $name ?>
    array(
       'required'  => 'Full Name is required' 
       // for validator to execute is_required()
    ));
$form->add_field( 
   'email' ,
    array( 
       'required'  => 'Email Address is required', 
       'email'     => 'A valid email address is required' 
       // for validator to execute is_email()
    ));
$form->add_field( 'country' );

//name of submit button
$for->add_submitter( 'submit' );
// etc 

$page = new Template();
$page->use_file( 'contact.php' );

if( $form->is_submitted() )
{
   // gathers all the $_POST's from registered fields
   $form->collect();

   if ($form->is_valid() )
   {
      $page->use_file( 'done.html' );
      // do some stuff 
   }
   else
   {            
      // public function populate( TemplateInterface $template )
      // assigns field values and error messages to the template
      $form->populate( $page );         
   }

}

echo $page->render();
```

And the `Template` class based upon this code : http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

---

**update**

Implementation for method that registers new fields

```
public function add_field( $name , array $rules = array() )
{       
   if ( !array_key_exists( $name , $this->_fields ))
   {
      $this->_fields[ $name ] = array();
   }

   $this->_fields[ $name ]['rules'] = $rules; 
}
```

Implementation for method that finds values of all the registered fields

```
public function collect()
{           
   $field_names = array_keys( $this->_fields );

   foreach ( $field_names as $name )
   {                
      $this->_fields[ $name ]['value'] = $this->_collect_value( $name );                
   }

}

protected function _collect_value($name)
{

   $value = null;

   if ( isset( $_POST[ $name ] ) )
   {
      $value = $_POST[$name];       
   }

   $value = trim( $value );

   if ( empty( $value ) ){
      $value = null;    
   }

   return $value;

}
```

The data collection is pretty simple process.

And on the `is_valid()` method call if get the Validator instance from local variable and performs actions on each registered form field ( mostly with helpfule php [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function.

Comment: Thanks Teresko, not exactly what I was looking for but close. I was looking for peoples thoughts on the 'processing' part of the form/s like this for example: `// gathers all the $_POST's from registered fields
   $form->collect();` Would this method just be getting and sorting the global variables like $_POST and $_GET and is that how most people or frameworks would do it?

Comment: @Steve Took im not sure what you mean by "processing" then , because validation of `Form` elements is not a responsibility of form itself. This is why it should require an external `Validator` provided in constructor. Form only need to gather all the data.

Comment: To use your terminology teresko 'data collection' is what I was getting at ;-) the way those methods are collecting data fits very nicely to what we've achieved so far. Weve got methods for registering form elements and validation already so this concept will work well, thank you very much. Your a legend!

Answer (score 1):

You're all missing very important concept. You don't want to show form, you want to ask user for some input. You actually want something like this:

```
$rules = array(
  "name" => array("not_empty"),
  "email" => array("not_empty", "email")
);
$callback = array($this, "handle_valid_post_data");
$ui->request_input($rules, $callback);
```

Sadly, no framework does this so you have to implement it yourself.